# dap-mode cpptools gives error `VTerm needs module support`

Tags: debugging, c++, lsp

I am trying to use dap-mode to debug my C++ code.
My debug template looks like:

```lisp
(dap-register-debug-template
  "cpptools::Run Configuration"
  (list :type "cppdbg"
        :request "launch"
        :name "cpptools::Run Configuration"
        :MIMode "gdb"
        :program "${workspaceFolder}/install/bin/examples/dealii_function_test"
        :cwd "${workspaceFolder}"))
```

When I try to run the debugger, I get this error:

```
error in process filter: VTerm needs module support. Please compile Emacs with the --with-modules option!
```

I don't really know what vterm is, and I haven't run into this problem before while debugging.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

The resolution was to update my versions of emacs and spacemacs.
For the latter, if you're on the develop branch you can just go to the `.emacs.d` folder (where the spacemacs configuration files are) and `git pull` to get the newest version.

For the latter, the newest version of emacs available from `apt` on Ubuntu is not compatible with the newest version of spacemacs, so you have to go [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html) to download from source and install.
Just for reference, once I downloaded and unzipped the source files, I made a build directory in the source folder `mkdir build && cd build`.
Then I just ran the configuration file from there `../configure`.
There were several dependencies that I was missing, so I had to install those with `apt` -- the output from the configuration file will throw an error and tell you what packages you're missing.
Finally you run `sudo make install` from the build directory to install emacs.

Once that was squared away, whichever layers were dependent on vterm (I guess the dap-debug layer) automatically installed it.